# How could I use vba to check if dates are the same?

Tags: vba, date, equals

I'm trying to write a code on cells that have both dates and times in them (Example: 1/29/14 9:15 AM). I'm trying to see if the date from 1 cell matches the date on another cell. How could I do that?

Example:

A1: 2/13/14    B1: 2/13/14  - This would return True

A2: 1/15/14    B2: 4/25/14  - This would return false

Any way I could achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores dates as fractional numbers where the whole number represents the date and the fraction represents the time of day (e.g., 0.5 = noon).  The whole number is the number of days since 1/1/1900.  So Excel stores `1/3/1900 6:00 PM` internally as `3.75`.

As long as they are formatted as dates, you can compare them directly:

```
C1 formula: =(A1=B1)
C2 formula: =(A2=B2)
```

To ignore the time portion of the date, take the integer portion only:

```
C1 formula: =(INT(A1)=INT(B1))
C2 formula: =(INT(A2)=INT(B2))
```

There's no real need for VBA, but if you want to compare the dates in VBA, the same rules apply:

```
Sub CompareDates()
    With ActiveSheet
        .[C1] = (Int(.[A1]) = Int(.[B1]))
        .[C2] = (Int(.[A2]) = Int(.[B2]))
    End With
End Sub
```